# New to Perl, where to start?

Tags: perl, cgi

I moved to a team where they mainly work on perl. The focus is on extending command line tools and fixing some web scripts written in perl. I have never worked on perl before. Could you please guide me where to start learning perl? How to go about it?

Could someone please suggest some books to start with and/or any good online tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)

Comment: I dont know if that is not allowed here.. apologies if this is wrong channel to ask such questions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are very good materials to learn Perl on the web. Some of these are:-

1. [Where and how to start learning Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284175)
2. http://perl-tutorial.org/
3. http://learn.perl.org/
4. [Beginning Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is a lot of material..

Answer (score 2):

2 books I would recommend for developers moving to Perl from other languages are Damian Conway's Perl Best Practices and the Perl Cookbook, both published by O'Reilly. They aren't books for beginners, but in my experience the main challenge faced by experienced programmers coming to Perl from other languages is basically choosing 'the best way' to do things.

Comment: Don't you think that the Perl Cookbook is a bit dated now?

Comment: I have heard that perl cookbook is very heavy and for a new person who does not know perl, its difficult to start with that book .. i will definately consider best practices book though. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @DaveCross In some respects, yes. A 3rd edition would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Are you an experienced programmer new to perl or new to programming in general?

The "standard" recommendation is  the [Camel book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000271.do), which I find unsuitable for novice programmers. But if you already have sufficient programming experience then you may find it useful.

Another recommendation is the [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) book

Comment: Second the recommendation for Modern Perl as a good place to start

Comment: experienced programmer new to perl.. thanks for your recommendations ! I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Perl by Schwartz et. al. is very good.

Also take a look at [this](http://perl-tutorial.org/) and [this](http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html).